# How to enable ScreenShare in peerJS

Tags: javascript, peerjs

I have implemented video chat feature already and the code is mentioned in the snippet below. But I am trying to make ScreenSharing work using the same PeerJS.

With reference to the answer [here](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/96), it says we have to get a screen sharing stream from getUserMedia instead of a webcam video stream. But exactly how do I do this in the following code:

```js
    var n = <any>navigator;
    
    n.getUserMedia = ( n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia || n.msGetUserMedia );
    
    n.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
    .then((stream) => {
        this.localStream = stream;
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
```

I understand what the above mentioned answer says, but how do I actually get a screen sharing stream from getUserMedia and change the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code you provided saves the stream (passed into the callback function to `this.localStream`. If you have a variable called screenShareStream, then this is the code you need:

```
// Your variable to refer to the stream:
var screenShareStream

var n = <any>navigator;

n.getUserMedia = ( n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia || n.msGetUserMedia );

n.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
.then((stream) => {
    screenShareStream = stream;
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
});
```

Comment: window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); this is deprecated  and the question is about screen sharing (getDisplayMedia) i think not about video-capturing (getUserMedia)